# phone:WebBrowser disable pan/zoom wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, zooming

I am using this code,

```
 <phone:WebBrowser Foreground="White" Opacity="0" Height="600" Width="430" x:Name="weblink" LoadCompleted="weblink_LoadCompleted" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

in this code i want to disable pan/zoom in phone:WebBrowser.

if anyone know the idea please share here.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can change the HTML maybe you can add the viewport metadata:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

I use it in my WP7 app (Stacks for Instapaper) to display web pages with specific width so the reading experience is not hampered by zooming/panning

I use this values:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`, and you can no longer do interactions on the control.

ie. `<phone:WebBrowser IsHitTestVisible="False" ... />`

Comment: IsHitTestVisible="False" this code hide for scrolling also, i want to scroll, only hide pin/zoom.

Comment: From a users Point of View, scrolling and panning is the same action. You can't specific disable left/right panning, or zooming. You shouldn't use a WebBrowser control for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a better way capturing the manipulation events, if it is in WP7.5 Mango since the browser controls are completely different, which I read from this [link](http://marker.to/DT7wvL). I have marked the important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The webbbrowser control in Windows Phone still allows for zoom and scroll because this is done on a control "above" the actual browser component.

This can be disabled in C# (additionally you can probably detect right/left vs up/down scroll gestures and suppress them individually)

See this blog entry for a full description:
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/

Peter