# How to Simulate a swipe on WP7 Pivot control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a WebBrowser control on of the pages of the Pivot control, so this will disable all my gestures on Pivot control since webbrowser is consuming all of them.
So I am adding an invisible grid over the browser, So all the actions on the grid should be applied on the pivot control. So I want to know if the default gestureListener for the control can be overriden so that it can be automated.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Why do you use 2 pivot controls when you want them to stay in sync?

Comment: @SinhPham I gave a simple example for users to understand and visualize. But that is the flow I am looking for. If this is confusing for other I will change my question. But my purpose is how to simulate a gesture on a control.

Comment: Does the WebBrowser control need to be interactive? You could just disable its hit detection if not.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516497/phonewebbrowser-disable-pan-zoom-wp7/9314297#9314297) This is one of the answers I gave to a question where Browser control is in pivotPage. So all the gestures will be in your control now, but how are you going to send these actions to the pivot control.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the following blog post :-

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston

Comment: I want exactly the same feel of swiping. And by the way I am already doing it using the selectedIndex but I am not getting the exact flow.

Comment: I answered one the questions with the same [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516497/phonewebbrowser-disable-pan-zoom-wp7/9314297#9314297). Even with that approach you will not be able to automate the gesture action on the pivot control it should be exactly reacting to user's action.

Answer (score 0):

This could be problematic if you want to be able to scroll inside the browser control, but you can just disable all gestures from targeting the browser control, then all gestures would just pass through the control and target the pivot instead. You can add `IsHitTestVisible="False"` to the browser control, or if you programatically created it `browserControl.IsHitTestVisible = false;`

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516497/phonewebbrowser-disable-pan-zoom-wp7/9314297#9314297) This is one of the answers I gave to a question where Browser control is in pivotPage. So all the gestures will be in your control now, but how are you going to send these actions to the pivot control.

Comment: The gestures don't need to be passed to the pivot control, they should just pass down to the next hit visible target which would be the underlying pivot.

Comment: That happens in normal case, but if a browser control is available you need to take the control from it like what i told in the link i gave earlier so no how are you going to pass this info to the pivot control.