# Content zoomed out using .NET WebBrowser control in Windows CE 7

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, windows-ce

I've recently upgraded to Windows CE7 for one of my personal projects written in C#. As you may know, CE7 introduced touch support, so the WebBrowser control works differently in regards to panning and zooming.

Here's my setup:

- Windows CE7 running on an Atom processor
- Using mouse and keyboard as inputs
- **Edit**: Targeting framework 2.0

The problem:

- When you load a page in the WebBrowser, it appears zoomed out by default
- I can't seem to find a way to render the page in it's original size
- I can't use the mouse scroll to zoom in
- The images in the web page look pixelated because of that

Any idea why this is happening and if there's a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my question was similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516497/phonewebbrowser-disable-pan-zoom-wp7)

You need to add metadata to the web page you want to display. Thankfully I have access to those pages which will make my job easier. Otherwise you need to play around the content and add this tag programmatically.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

PS. I honestly didn't know how closely related WP7 and CE7 were. Now I know.