# How to disable zoom on window phone

Tags: jquery, html

I m working on a project and I m facing zoom problem on tab and pinch on windows phone, please help me to solve guys I want to disable this problem
[image]

Comment: Try something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`. There most important part for you is `user-scalable=no`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

There is an explanation [here](http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/353/windows-phone-7-disabling-the-default-pinch-zoom-scroll-snapback-behavior).
And there is a relative [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300610/disable-double-tap-zoom-on-windows-phone) in SO.

Comment: I always use this meta and its work fine, but for now it's not working :(

Comment: Have you used this? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 0):

Include below meta tag on your page that would help you to disable tap and zoom issue of your window phone

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```